# What is more performatic way to extract patterns from large file (over 700MB)

Tags: java, performance, parsing, large-files

I've a problem which requires me to parse a text file from local machine. There are a few complications:

1. The files can be quite large (700mb+)
2. The pattern occurs in multiple lines
3. I need store line information after the pattern

I've created a simple code using `BufferReader`, `String.indexOf` and `String.substring` (to get item 3).

Inside the file it has a key (pattern) named `code=` that occurs many times in different blocks. The program read each line from this file using `BufferReader.readLine`. It uses `indexOf` to check if the pattern appears and then it extract text after pattern and store in a common string.

When I ran my program with 600mb file, I noticed that performance was worst while it process file. I read an article in CodeRanch that `Scanner` class isn't performatic for large files.

Are there some techniques or a library that could improve my performance ?

Thanks in advance.

Here's my source code:

```
String codeC = "code=[";
String source = "";
try {
    FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream("c:\\Temp\\fo1.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(f1);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String strLine;
    boolean bPrnt = false;
    int ln = 0;
    // Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Print the content on the console
        if (strLine.indexOf(codeC) != -1) {
            ln++;
            System.out.println(strLine + " ---- register : " + ln);
            strLine = strLine.substring(codeC.length(), strLine.length());
            source = source + "\n" + strLine;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Lines :" + ln);
    f1.close();
} catch ( ... ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In addition to what has been suggested by @Marko below I would suggest you collect your results in a StringBuilder, or better still a List<String>. Building it as one potentially huge String could impact your memory footprint dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

This code of yours is highly suspicious and may well account for at least a part of your performance issues:

```
FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream("c:\\Temp\\fo1.txt");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(f1);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

You are involving `DataInputStream` for no good reason, and in fact using it as an input to a `Reader` can be considered a case of broken code. Write this instead:

```
InputStream f1 = new FileInputStream("c:\\Temp\\fo1.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr));
```

A huge detriment to performance is the `System.out` you are using, especially if you measure the performance when running in Eclipse, but even if running from the command line. My guess is, this is the major cause of your bottleneck. By all means ensure you don't print anything in the main loop when you aim for top performance.

Comment: I mean he is inserting a `DataInputStream` into the chain. That's what is not needed. The readers part is OK.

Comment: Should he not better use br.close() instead of f1.close() ?

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to use `br.close()`, yes, but it doesn't affect performance, and the system resource (the open file) will get released either way.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Marko answered, I suggest to close the br, not the f1:

```
br.close()
```

This will not affect the performance, but is cleaner. (closing the outermost stream)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [java.util.regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)

An excellent [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) from oracle.

A copy paste from the JAVADoc:

> Classes for matching character sequences against patterns specified by regular expressions.
>
> An instance of the Pattern class represents a regular expression that is specified in string form in a syntax similar to that used by Perl.
>
> Instances of the Matcher class are used to match character sequences against a given pattern. Input is provided to matchers via the CharSequence interface in order to support matching against characters from a wide variety of input sources.
>
> Unless otherwise noted, passing a null argument to a method in any class or interface in this package will cause a NullPointerException to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly !!

I followed **OldCurmudgeon**, **Marko Topolnik** and **AlexWien** advices and my performance improved 1000%. Before the program spent 2 hours to complete described operation and write a response in file. 
Now it spends 5 minutes !! And SYSO remains in source code !!

I think that reason of great improvement is change String "source" for HashSet "source" like OldCurmudgeon suggests. Bur I removed DataInputStream and used "br.close" too.

Thanks guys !!

Comment: I think the most improvement was the remove of System.out.prinltn().